# Netbeans remote project with Git repository

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-7, bitbucket

I have a remote project in Netbeans, I mean that I have local copy of SFTP project and when I perform changes I can upload them directly to the server.

Now I want commit all changes to Bitbucket repository as well. How can I associate my project sources with repository. When I try to perform `Team -> Git -> Clone` Netbeans says that folder is not empty and can't clone project from repository.

Have you some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

1. Clone new project from Git repository.
2. After cloning simply crate new Remote Project and set created on first step source directory.

That's all. This order is important.

Comment: HI! I have the same problem, but with your solution it looks as I will end with 2 repos, one in local and one in remote. Are you having issues when trying to keep them synchronized? I mean, you have now two repos that must have the same code, and git in both, so, are you commiting in both repos all the time?

Comment: @Chococroc Yes, you do have two repos, that is normal, if you were in a group of developers and you were using git, every developer would have a local repo where he would work in and you all would share one central remote repo. That is how Git is usually used.